# Django JSONField with arrays filtering by substring

Tags: python, django, orm

I've got a `events` JSONField in my model and I want to filter by value on key. Example object creation:

```
MyModel.objects.create(
    name="test", 
    events=[
        {"type": "created", "info": "xxx"}, 
        {"type": "sent", "info": "abc"}, 
    ]
)
```

So in `events` I have a list of events with same keys but different value. I want to filter by `name` and `info` values for doing autocompletion feature - so I need to filter by string icontains in `info`.

What I figured out is
`MyModel.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains='abc') | Q(events__info__0__icontains='abc'))` but it takes only first event from a list - if `info` match in second element then it is not placed in results.

Is it possible to do with django orm?

I want something like
`MyModel.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains='abc') | Q(events__info__<all>__icontains='abc'))`

Comment: If the data is structured, as appears to be the case here, it makes not much sense to use a `JSONFIeld` in a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(event__contains=[{"info": 'abc'}])
```